# Dynamically insert class="active" into php function that generates bootstrap menu

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried pretty much every solution that was available online but cannot get the class="active" to change dynamically for each menu section.

When someone clicks the top level menu item it opens up the second level menu and if someone click the on a second level menu item in that section class="active" needs to remain on the top level menu li tag.

I have the following function that generates my bootstrap menu:

```
function getMenu() {
global $connection;
mysqli_select_db($connection, "c9");
$query = ("SELECT testName, testId FROM testType");
$result_set = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set)) {
    $testId = $row['testId'];
    $testName = $row['testName'];
        echo '<li>'; //This is where class="active" needs to be added
        echo '<a href="#"><span class="nav-label">'.$testName.'</span></a>';
        echo '<ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">';
        echo '<li><a href="/dashboard/?type=doTest&testId='.$testId.'">Summary Report</a></li>';
        echo '<li><a href="/dashboard/?type=doTest&testId='.$testId.'">Add Data</a></li>';
        echo '</ul>';
        echo '</li>';
}
```

}

And the menu structure is as follows:

```
   <ul class="nav metismenu" id="side-menu">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="/">
                    <span class="nav-label">Summary</span> 
                <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse in">
                    <li><a href="dashboard_5.html">Reports</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
             <li><a href="#">
                 <span class="nav-label">Temperature</span>
                 <ul class="nav nav-second-level collapse">
                     <li><a href="/dashboard/?type=doTest&amp;testId=1">Summary Report</a></li>
                     <li><a href="/dashboard/?type=doTest&amp;testId=1">Add Data</a></li>
              </ul>
```

Comment: question not clear! what do you mean by "add the class active dynamically"? it's on "hover"?

Comment: you are right. I have updated the questions. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: You should consider a template engine like smarty or twig. With that tool this problem becomes trivial.

Comment: so, for example when the user is on the "Add Data" submenu, then you need the "temperature" and "add data" to have "active class" ?

Comment: @Julo0sS Temperature is the parent menu item for the section so active needs to be on its li tag. That way when someone clicks on Add Data or Report for that section it doesnt collapse the menu section.